# Sind Fragen nach Übersetzungen vom Deutschen ins Englische off -topic?

Tags: discussion

Die Frage [Translation of "Autoritätsdusel ist der größte Feind der Wahrheit" (Einstein, 1901)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/72665/47079) wurde kürzlich als off-topic geschlossen. Die Begründung ist nachvollziehbar. Andererseits gibt es den Tag "german-to-english" mit der Beschreibung

> Übersetzung Deutsch nach Englisch - Questions on translations of a single word or phrase from German to English.

Das trifft m.E. auf die geschlossene Frage zu - oder verstehe ich den Tag falsch?

1. War die Frage also doch legitim?
2. Falls nein, sollte der Tag "german-to-english" gelöscht werden, weil er zu Missverständnissen Anlass gibt?

Answer (score 5):

Ich empfinde die konkrete Frage als legitim, weil es ihr um die Interpretation des Wortes *Autoritätsdusel* geht und dieses Wort bestimmt nicht selbsterklärend ist.

Allgemeiner gesprochen: Wenn es bei Übersetzungen um die Feinheiten der Bedeutung des Deutschen (und nicht der Zielsprache) geht, sollten solche Fragen zulässig sein.

Comment: Ich würde ein re-open vote der genannten Frage unterstützen.

Answer (score 3):

Was als Frage nach der besten Übersetzung ins Englische formuliert wird, kann häufig als Frage nach der Interpretation des deutschen Ausdrucks verstanden werden. Bevor wir schließen, sollten wir stärker versuchen, die Frage zu retten. Das letzte ist eine Aussage, die nicht nur auf diese Fallgruppe von Fragen zutrifft.

Ein close-vote ist auch nicht in Stein gemeißelt. Wenn die Frage editiert wird, kann sie auch wieder geöffnet werden. Es sollte unser Ziel sein, stärker und konstruktiver mit den Fragesteller:innen zusammenzuarbeiten, um die Frage zu retten.

Jede Frage eines Neulings sollten wir als die Chance begreifen, dass hier ein neues und produktives Mitglied der Community heranwächst, und dass eine gerettete Frage für spätere Leser:innen des Forums sinnvoll sein kann. Meiner subjektiven Wahrnehmung nach sollte das Verhältnis zwischen "policing" und "community service" zugunsten letzterens verändert werden.

Eine Frage zu retten bedeutet mehr Aufwand, als sie zu schließen, und möglicherweise haben wir nicht die Resourcen dafür. Vielleicht ist ein Teil des Phänomens jedoch auch eine Bewusstseinsfrage.

Answer (score 2):

Ich sehe das weitgehend wie David Vogt, und ich finde auch, der Schließgrund "translating or proofreading a text" wird hier sehr weit weg von seiner eigentlichen Intention benutzt. Ich sehe den Sinn dieses Schließgrunds darin, dass uns die Leute hier nicht z.B. ihre Briefe an ihren Vermieter zur Übersetzung ins Deutsche vorlegen, oder ihren in Deutsch geschriebenen Brief zur Korrektur.

Konkrete Fragen dazu, wie ein einzelner deutschrn Satz -- eigentlich hier ein einzelnes Wort -- zu verstehen oder zu übersetzen ist, zählen für mich nicht dazu.

Bezogen auf die konkrete Frage: ich finde schon, dass die Frage, so wie sie gestellt ist, nämlich als Vergleich verschiedener vorhandener Übersetzungen, gute Englisch-Kenntnisse benötigt und auf eine Meinung darüber abzielt, wie Einstein den Satz gemeint hat. In dieser Form finde ich sie deshalb streng genommen offtopic. Als konkrete Frage, wie man das Wort *Autoritätsdusel* oder auch das ganze Zitat verstehen kann, fände ich sie legitim, und entsprechend habe ich sie dann auch beantwortet.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann nur unterstützen, was @JonathanScholbach ausgeführt hat. Die anderen Antworten hier stellen grundlegend eher darauf ab, unter genau welchen Umständen Fragen zu schließen sind und wie die Regeln ausgelegt werden dürfen/sollen/müssen.

Abseits dieser "juristischen" Argumentation stellt sich aber die Frage, welchem generellen Zweck dieses Forum dient und wem damit geholfen ist. Mit ein wenig gutem (das heißt: bösem) Willen kann man vermutlich für die meisten Fragen irgendwelche Schließgründe finden. Die Frage wäre dann aber, wozu ein Forum gut sein soll, in dem die Beteiligten hauptsächlich nach Schließgründen anstatt nach Antworten suchen.

Ich sage ausdrücklich NICHT, daß das der Fall wäre, aber das ist die Richtung, vor der ich warnen möchte. Abseits der Regeln (die gut und notwendig sind, aber eben als Leitlinie, nicht als in Stein gemeißelte Gesetze) sollte die Grundfrage bei jeder (auch dieser) Entscheidung lauten: *womit ist dem Bestand des Forums am meisten gedient* und nicht *unter welchen Umständen kann ich welche Regel auch an der ursprünglichen Intention vorbei anwenden*.